# Defining file location in log4j2.xml after deploying WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, configuration, log4j2

I have gotten my print to file to work for log4j2 logging, but when deploying my project as a WAR onto a tomcat server, I cant seem to find where the log file is sent. I have the following log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="AE" fileName="/AE.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} -  
%msg%n"/>
    </File>
      <File name="BP" fileName="/BP.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - 
%msg%n"/>
    </File>
      <File name="CBK" fileName="/CBK.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} -    
%msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug" />
        <AppenderRef ref="AE" level="debug"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="BP" level="debug"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="CBK" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Is there a way that I can properly define my filename paths so that after having deployed my WAR file, my logs are sent to somewhere such as WEB-INF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the disappearing log files, could it be that the user that is running the tomcat server does not have permission to write files to the root directory?

About your filename path question, it is possible to use system properties in the path by using the ${sys:some.property} syntax.

Comment: I was actually able to get it working by defining my path as "${sys:catalina.home}/logs/ae.log", and my log file location comes out to tomcat/logs/ae.log, which is the tomcat being used to deploy my war. So in terms of your syntax, this is correct.